# Which tense is that : avoir + être au passé + participe passé du verbe

Tags: temps-grammatical, conjugaison, voix-passive

Many times I found this form of tense *avoir + être au passé + participe passé du verbe*, for example :

> il a été happé

but I don't find it as a French tense.

Do you have any idea what it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's 'le passé composé d'un verbe conjugué à la voix passive' (passive form).

Full details for 'happer' [here](https://www.conjugaisonfrancaise.com/happer-voix-passive.html).

"il a été happé" = "he has been caught" or "he was caught" depending on the context

Comment: okeeey, thank you for your response